# MVC2: How to mask a simple dot in a string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

This works fine:

Controller.cs

```
ViewData["MyText"] = "Hello World";
```

Index.aspx

```
<%: Html.Label(ViewData["MyText"].ToString()) %>
```

But the complete text is not displayed when I add just a dot "." to "Hello World".
I thought "<%:" takes care for this but it seams that this is not true...

How to solve this?
How to mask the dot?

Changing "." with "%2E" doesnt work ;-(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using the Label() extension correctly. Try this:

```
<%: Html.Label("MyText") %>
```

or this:

```
<label><%: ViewData["MyText"] %></label>
```

Comment: Thanks you very muc hthis works! (sorry I am a MVC beginner/newbie)